# Android Studio 20.20.3.1 cant import spotify app-remote module

Tags: android, android-studio, import, module, spotify

Similar questions have been found, but I cant even get past the module import.
Referring to this guide: https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/android/quick-start/kotlin/

The part headed **"Add The App Remote SDK"** screenshots dont match the current version of Android Studio, however there is an Import option in the **Create New Module** dialog.

I downloaded the sdk from github, and extracted into a folder...
F:\spotify-android-sdk-master\android-sdk-master

When selecting that path, the dialog lists 4 modules. app-remote-lib, app-remote-sample, auth-lib, and auth-sample.

HOWEVER ... I cant add any of them! I want to add app-remote-lib but Previous, Next, and Finish buttons are always disabled, only Cancel is available button.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
I've tried changing the module names, and unticking all but app-remote-lib. Nothing sseems to work.

Thanks and regards,
Al

Comment: You could try the adding it manually as described here: https://pub.dev/packages/spotify_sdk